# How to create expanding line animation from this base?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

So I want to create this animation where basically this happens:
When you hover on an icon, it gets bigger, increases in opacity, and some text appears.
In addition to this, 2 lines of color extend in width from the center out to the sides, then they increase in height.
The bottom color should expand downwards, while the top color should expand upwards.
I created this test-base and was wondering how I would go about making this from here. I tried tweaking the height, width, and opacity but those also edit the icon, so I'm wondering if I'm taking the wrong approach or just doing it wrong. Any help and/or pointers are appreciated.

**Current code:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Consolas";
}

body {
  background: #212121;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.hoverCard {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #191919;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hoverCard::before {
  background: blue;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.hoverCard .mainImg {
  opacity: 0.25;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 10;
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.hoverCard .mainText {
  opacity: 0;
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 0%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.hoverCard .subText {
  opacity: 0;
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 0%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.mainImg:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.mainImg:hover~.mainText {
  margin-top: 20%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mainImg:hover~.subText {
  margin-top: 25%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hoverCard">
    <img class="mainImg" src="../Media/Link-Logos/Discord.png">
    <p class="mainText">Discord</p>
    <p class="subText">Ex0tic_Python#7571</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, is everything OK apart from those two lines of color not being there yet?

Comment: The code I provided works just fine for the end should basically look like, but doesn't have the line expanding animation, and am unsure of how to go about it.

Comment: So to start with when the user isn't hovering what should it look like? For example would there be no blue and that blackish background colors? Do the lines have those colors?

Comment: When there is no hover, there should only be the icon with 0.25 opacity. Then on hover, the Icon enlarges, increases in opacity, and 2 lines extend out to each side, 1 grey and 1 blue per side. Then they expand up and down to create the entire card (flexbox) if that makes any sense.

Comment: But in the final position on hover there is 50% blue and 50% blackish, so the lines extend not from the center of the image but from the center of the card? Is that right? So hovering on the image creates color not related to the position of the image?

Comment: Actually, yeah. That's a good point and correct. It's not relative to the image but to the center of the card.
It would look something like this:
https://ibb.co/Yb6SPKC

Comment: Also, the image is a bit inaccurate. The line doesn't have to be centered with the logo, as the logo moves up. If anything, in the end, the logo will be a bit higher then the line between the grey and blue.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer, particularly the position of the 'lines' and the fact that they carry on increasing after the image has stopped increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the requirement is to have lines drawn and expanding when the image is hovered, and the image itself cannot have pseudo elements, this snippet adds a further element after the img, .lines.

This is positioned absolutely and sized relative to the overall card (parent) element.

It has before and after pseudo elements which draw lines and then expand vertically using a CSS animation.

As I was unclear what you wanted to happen about the line going downwards (if it keeps the same background color as the card then of course it can't be seen) so this snippet makes it pink.

Of course you will want to alter timings and perhaps dimensions to suit your specific requirements, this is just a simple example to demonstrate one possibility.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Consolas";
    }
    
    body {
      background: #212121;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .hoverCard {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 320px;
      height: 480px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .hoverCard .mainImg {
      opacity: 0.25;
      height: 160px;
      width: 160px;
      transition: 0.5s;
      margin: 10;
      margin-top: 50%;
    }
    
    .hoverCard .mainText {
      opacity: 0;
      color: blue;
      margin-top: 0%;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .hoverCard .subText {
      opacity: 0;
      color: blue;
      margin-top: 0%;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .mainImg:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      opacity: 1;
      margin-top: 30%;
    }
    
    .mainImg:hover~.mainText {
      margin-top: 20%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .mainImg:hover~.subText {
      margin-top: 25%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .lines {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: #191919;
    }
    
    .lines::before,
    .lines::after {
      content: '';
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      width: 160px;
      height: 10px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .lines::before {
      background-color: blue;
      bottom: 50%;
    }
    
    .lines::after {
      background-color: pink;
      top: 50%;
    }
    
    @keyframes expand {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 160px;
        height: 10px;
      }
      9.99% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      10% {
        width: 240px;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10px;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    .mainImg:hover~.lines::before,
    .mainImg:hover~.lines::after {
      display: block;
      animation: expand 3s linear forwards 0.3s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hoverCard">
    <img class="mainImg" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200">
    <div class="lines"></div>
    <p class="mainText">Discord</p>
    <p class="subText">Ex0tic_Python#7571</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'll take a look at the code and see what does what, and then I'll tweak it to my needs. Very much appreciated